# watershed segmentation in matlab

Tags: matlab

anyone knows how to write a function in matlab to segment the soil and compute the average soil area using the watershed algorithm? any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!  Here is an image of the soil[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnx9W.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? What did you expect to happen? Why happened instead?

Comment: am stuck at here                                                                                       bw = imbinarize();
figure
imshow(bw),, it keep show Undefined function 'imbinarize' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.

Comment: You need to provide an image file as an argument for imbinarize